Active Directory stops working after a few hours of joining a domain on Ubuntu Desktop 22.04
Basically we joined the domain to Active Directory and it was working fine but after a few hours the join domain feature stopped working for some reason and users who had never logged in to Ubuntu Desktop could not log in but users who had logged in already could still be able to Login.
I thought the kerberos ticket had expired but apparently not and it still doesnt work even though we renewed the kerberos ticket.
After checking, I tried to rejoin the domain and the user was able to login to the ubuntu desktop but the problem is I have to rejoin the domain every few hours which means it is very complicated.
I don't know why the join domain or Active Directory stops working after a few hours and it looks like the session has expired.
Please help me to investigate and resolve this issue.
Thank You.

The question reads like the issue is only on the Active Domain not on Ubuntu. A Windows issue?

Ubuntu/Linux uses a service for this: check journalctl for notifications. But ... this is more than likely either a network issue or a problem on the Windows end.

After checking the journalctl, I found this log.
"Access denied for user user-a: 4 (System error)"
